# Offline conversion of Microsoft Office and PDF docs to HTML

Tags: php

is there any open source / paid converter available to convert Microsoft Office and PDF documents to HTML so your users can view them right in the web app, and particularly looking for something which does it offline. Scribd, crocdoc, google doc viewer would work for online, have a requirement to make it work offline. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Since you need some type of processing you won't get around having at least a local server running to do that (despite of having desktop utilities).

Comment: Have you tried OpenOffice? Though this is hardly a 'PHP' question, since PHP is meant to be 'online'.

Comment: Would be using Apache/wamp to run the application locally. The idea is to convert the docs to HTML while running the application (or convert docs to HTML format while uploading itself) and hence will be able to open it browser itself rather than having to download/open it with other desktop application like MS Office tools.                                                           Tried embedding, iframe to open documents in HTML window, could not open all formats like ppts, docx.